# Appendices at section level in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, appendices

I would like my appendices to appear in TOC at section level instead of at chapter level.

Like this:

```
    Appendices
        A  My appendix 1 . . . . . . .
        B  My appendix 2 . . . . . . .
```

I've tried with `\settocdepth` but it does not work.

My code:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}     % english language
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % accents in source
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % accents in DVI
    \usepackage{color}              % add color to the text
    \definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
    \definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
    \definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}

    \usepackage{graphicx}           % images in the document
    \usepackage{float}              % containers
    \usepackage{wrapfig}            % wrap text around figure

    \usepackage{vmargin}            % redefine the margins
    \setmarginsrb{2.5cm}{1.5cm}{2.5cm}{1cm}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}{1cm}

    \usepackage[
    hyperindex=true, % add links in the index
    bookmarks=true,  % show bookmarks bar when displaying the document}{hyperref}
    ]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, % colored links
    breaklinks=true, % allows return line in too long links
    urlcolor= blue,  % links color
    linkcolor= blue, % internal links color
    citecolor= blue, % green by defaut, color of citation links (bibliography)
    bookmarksopen=true,
    pdftitle={Cloud 3D Teapot},
    pdfauthor={Jos\'{e} L\'{o}pez C\'{i}vico},
    pdfsubject={Cloud Latency}
    }

    \usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % code font size
    numbers=left,                   % place of numbers
    numberstyle=\normalsize,        % numbers font size
    numbersep=7pt,                  % distance between code and its numeration
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % background color
    }

    \lstdefinestyle{CSharp}{
      language=[Sharp]C,
      showspaces=false,
      showtabs=false,
      breaklines=true,
      showstringspaces=false,
      breakatwhitespace=true,
      escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
      commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
      keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
      stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
      basicstyle=\ttfamily
    }

    \lstdefinestyle{XMLc}{
      language=XML,
      showspaces=false,
      showtabs=false,
      breaklines=true,
      showstringspaces=false,
      breakatwhitespace=true,
      stringstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
      keywordstyle=\color{redstrings},
      morekeywords={name, connectionString, providerName},
      commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
      basicstyle=\ttfamily
    }

    \usepackage{titlepic}
    \usepackage{appendix}

    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{kpfonts}

    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \listoffigures
    \newpage

    \chapter{Test Chapter}
    \section{A Regular Section}

\appendix
\clearpage % or \cleardoublepage
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc
% code to show appendices at section level in TOC
\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Installation requirements}
\chapter{Acronyms}
\end{appendices}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: the document class used was `report`, so here's now the solution with the actual settings:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}     % english language
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % accents in source
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % accents in DVI
\usepackage{color}              % add color to the text
\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}

\usepackage{graphicx}           % images in the document
\usepackage{float}              % containers
\usepackage{wrapfig}            % wrap text around figure

\usepackage{vmargin}            % redefine the margins
\setmarginsrb{2.5cm}{1.5cm}{2.5cm}{1cm}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}{1cm}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % code font size
    numbers=left,                   % place of numbers
    numberstyle=\normalsize,        % numbers font size
    numbersep=7pt,                  % distance between code and its numeration
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % background color
 }

\lstdefinestyle{CSharp}{
      language=[Sharp]C,
      showspaces=false,
      showtabs=false,
      breaklines=true,
      showstringspaces=false,
      breakatwhitespace=true,
      escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
      commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
      keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
      stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
      basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\lstdefinestyle{XMLc}{
      language=XML,
      showspaces=false,
      showtabs=false,
      breaklines=true,
      showstringspaces=false,
      breakatwhitespace=true,
      stringstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
      keywordstyle=\color{redstrings},
      morekeywords={name, connectionString, providerName},
      commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
      basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage[
    hyperindex=true, % add links in the index
    bookmarks=true,  % show bookmarks bar when displaying the document}{hyperref}
    ]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, % colored links
    breaklinks=true, % allows return line in too long links
    urlcolor= blue,  % links color
    linkcolor= blue, % internal links color
    citecolor= blue, % green by defaut, color of citation links (bibliography)
    bookmarksopen=true,
    pdftitle={Cloud 3D Teapot},
    pdfauthor={Jos\'{e} L\'{o}pez C\'{i}vico},
    pdfsubject={Cloud Latency}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\chapassect{%
\def\@chapter[##1]##2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{section}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}##1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{##1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{##1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{##2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{##2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}%
}
\makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \listoffigures
    \newpage

    \chapter{Test Chapter}
    \section{A Regular Section}

\appendix
\clearpage % or \cleardoublepage
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc
% code to show appendices at section level in TOC
\chapassect
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Installation requirements}
\chapter{Acronyms}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I moved the `hyperref` package and loaded it last (except some well documented exceptions this should always be done).

Here's one option; the [`appendix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix) package was used to include "Appendices" in the ToC just before the appendices, and the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package was used to change the way chapter entries are typeset in the ToC, inside the `appendix` environment:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{A Regular Section}

\begin{appendix}
\addappheadtotoc
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [3.8em]
  {}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {\titlerule*[0.7em]{.}\contentspage}
\chapter{Test Appendix One}
\chapter{Test Appendix Two}
\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the above solution I assumed that appendices will be build using `\chapter`, and only the entries in the ToC must be changed; if the intent is to use `\section` to typeset the appendices, then it's enough to use the `subappendices` environment from the `appendix` package, and to redefine `\setthesection`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}

\renewcommand\setthesection{\Alph{section}} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{A Regular Section}

\addappheadtotoc
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Test Appendix One}
\section{Test Appendix Two}
\end{subappendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since, according to a comment, the `hyperref` package is being used, the `titletoc` solution won't be completely valid, since these two packages don't interact well; in this case, some extra work has to be done:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\chapassect{%
\def\@chapter[##1]##2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{section}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}##1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{##1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{##1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{##1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{##2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{##2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{A Regular Section}

\begin{appendix}
\addappheadtotoc
\chapassect
\chapter{Test Appendix One}
\chapter{Test Appendix Two}
\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code above assumed the `book` document class; after a comment, it seems that this class is not used, but unfortunately the actual document class is not mentioned in the comment; however, given the error message obtained by the OP after trying to implement my last suggestion, my crystal ball tells me that the document class might be `amsbook`. In this case the necessary redefinition is even simpler:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \ifnum\c@secnumdepth<\z@ \let\@secnumber\@empty
  \else \let\@secnumber\thechapter \fi
  \typeout{\chaptername\space\@secnumber}%
  \def\@toclevel{0}%
  \ifx\chaptername\appendixname \@tocwriteb\tocappendix{section}{#2}%
  \else \@tocwriteb\tocchapter{chapter}{#2}\fi
  \chaptermark{#1}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
  \@makechapterhead{#2}\@afterheading}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{A Regular Section}

\begin{appendix}
\addappheadtotoc
\chapter{Test Appendix One}
\chapter{Test Appendix Two}
\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Both of them work but I would prefer to use the first approach because of the use of chapter. If I use it, the A, B, etc. on TOC aren't in blue color (link) as the name of the appendix. And the dots don't finish where all the other dots.

Comment: @jlcivico yes, `titletoc` and `hyperref` don't play well together; please see my updated answer for a new solution compatible with the use of `hyperref`.

Comment: To which character does @ fit? Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: @jlcivico `@` is a special character for internal macros; redefining such macros (containing the character) in a `.tex` file requires `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` to perform a change in category codes. a detailed explanation can be found in the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/3954.

Comment: If I try to use it the next error pops up: ! Undefined control sequence.
\@chapter ...\c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \if@mainmatter
\refstepcounter {chapter}\...

Comment: @jlcivico then something is going on in your document; my solution will work for the standard book class; perhaps you are using another document class? If this is the case, then please edit your original question and add a complete and simply document illustrating your current settings (a short document like the ones in my examples), especially the document class you use (you have not yet provided this information). By the way (not that I care much), it's somehow rude to un-accpet a perfectly valid answer just because it doesn't work for you when you haven't provide relevant information.

Comment: @jlcivico I added a new example to my answer, assuming that you are using `amsbook`. If this is not so, please add to your question the simple complete document I asked for in my previous comment.

Comment: I thought a valid answer is this one that works for me. But if a valid answer is this one that works for somebody doing what I want, I am so sorry ;)

Comment: @jlcivico No need to apologize; in fact, you're right, you are the one who decide if the answer should be accepted or not, depending on whether it solves your problem. I only mentioned that it was a little rude to accept it and then unaccepted it without having mentioned crucial  information (in this case, the document class used) that would have save time. I hope my last example solves your problem :-) If not, please let me know and I'll try to provide a solution.

Comment: You are right, I'll take note of best practices to improve my questions. Besides, I didn't pay attention to the document class that you were using... big mistake

Comment: @jlcivico I've updated my answer with a solution using your current settings (the solution is at the top of my answer).

Comment: It works fine right now!! ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8037/discussion-between-jlcivico-and-gonzalo-medina)